# Assembly (or NASM) annoying problem

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb, nasm

I used to compile my asm code with TASM (on winXP) but I had some troubles so now I use NASM (on linux). This snippet shows what I'm trying to do:

```
(gdb) list 35
30      xor ecx,ecx             # ecx is a counter
31      mov bl, ' '             # this is what I'm looking for
32  count_spaces:
33      mov al,[esi]            # grab a char
34      jz  spaces_counted      # is this the end?
35      inc esi                 # next char
36      cmp al,bl               # found one?
37      jne count_spaces        # nope, loop
38      inc ecx                 # yep, inc counter
39      jmp count_spaces        # and loop
```

This looks correct to me, *but*:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at project1.asm:30
30      xor ecx,ecx
(gdb) display (char) $al
1: (char) $al = 0 '\000'
(gdb) display (char) $bl
2: (char) $bl = 0 '\000'
(gdb) next
31      mov bl, ' '
2: (char) $bl = 0 '\000'
1: (char) $al = 0 '\000'
(gdb) 
count_spaces () at project1.asm:33
33      mov al,[esi]
2: (char) $bl = 0 '\000'
1: (char) $al = 0 '\000'
(gdb)
```

I can't understand why `al` and `bl` didn't change.
I'm sure my code *is* correct, but.. I think I missed some NASM's option?
BTW I compiled with

```
nasm -f elf -l project1.lst -o project1.o -i../include/ -g  project1.asm
```

---

After compiling, I disassembled the output and got:

```
 80483ec:   31 c9                   xor    %ecx,%ecx
 80483ee:   bb 20 00 00 00          mov    $0x20,%ebx

080483f3 <count_spaces>:
 80483f3:   8b 06                   mov    (%esi),%eax
 80483f5:   3d 00 00 00 00          cmp    $0x0,%eax
 80483fa:   74 0b                   je     8048407 <spaces_counted>
 80483fc:   46                      inc    %esi
 80483fd:   39 d8                   cmp    %ebx,%eax
 80483ff:   75 f2                   jne    80483f3 <count_spaces>
 8048401:   41                      inc    %ecx
 8048402:   e9 ec ff ff ff          jmp    80483f3 <count_spaces>
```

Comment: Do I need to know Italian(presumably) to understand your variable names?

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: ups, I completely forgot that. :) edited

Comment: please note that gdb displays instructions __before__ executing them, so you need to 'stepi' or 'next' to have the displayed instruction executed. still, the value of bl should have changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that GDB doesn't know about the 8 or 16 bit aliased registers. It will always print 0 for `al, bl, ax, bx`, etc. You should use `eax, ebx`, etc:

```
(gdb) info registers bl
Invalid register `bl'
(gdb) info registers bx
Invalid register `bx'
(gdb) info registers ebx
ebx            0xf7730ff4       -143454220
(gdb) p $bl
$1 = void
(gdb) p $bx
$2 = void
(gdb) p $ebx
$3 = -143454220
(gdb) p/x $bl
$4 = Value can't be converted to integer.
(gdb) p/x $bx
$5 = Value can't be converted to integer.
(gdb) p/x $ebx
$6 = 0xf7730ff4
(gdb) p (char) $bl
$7 = 0 '\0'
(gdb) p (char) $bx
$8 = 0 '\0'
(gdb) p (char) $ebx
$9 = -12 'ô'
```

Comment: Thank you. So is the problem only with gdb? I mean, if I use @Matthew Slattery's trick can I still use bl and al?

Answer (score 6):

[Jester has the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212941/assembly-or-nasm-annoying-problem/5214324#5214324), and deserves an up-vote.

But, I'd like to add something which is too long for a comment: you can teach `gdb` to display sub-registers if you wish, using the [`hook-stop` hook](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Hooks.html#Hooks), which runs just before any `display` happens, by adding the following to your `.gdbinit` file:

```
define hook-stop
set $bl=($ebx & 0xff)
set $bh=(($ebx & 0xff00) >> 8)
set $bx=($ebx & 0xffff)
end
```

(extend in the obvious way for other registers).  `display $bl` etc. will then work as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's the problem you've noted, but I see one fairly obvious problem in your code. On the x86, a `mov` does *not* affect the flags. Your code:

```
33      mov al,[esi]            # grab a char
34      jz  spaces_counted      # is this the end?
```

Seems to assume that when you load `al` from `[esi]` that the `z` flag will be updated to reflect the content of al. That's *not* the case. To test whether the value you just loaded is zero, you need to add an explicit test:

```
mov al, [esi]
test al, al
jz spaces_counted
```

The value *in* the register should have changed before, but the flags should *not* have been updated to reflect the value.

As for whether nasm produced the right instructions, I'd disassemble the code to see what's really there. Right now, it's hard to guess whether the problem lies with nasm or with gdb. Of course, disassemblers aren't guaranteed to be bug-free either, but I'd be a bit surprised to see a problem with code this simple.

Comment: The output from objdump seems to indicate that the mov's were assembled as mov's, so nasm did it's job correctly. OTOH, the output you show from objdump does *not* match the source code that precedes it either.

Comment: that's a secondary problem because they're equivalent

Comment: @BlackBear: No, they're not -- the objdump output shows a "cmp" that's not present in the source code (but does cure the problem I (and @Diego) cited. I'm not sure if you added that later, or perhaps the source code you posted wasn't what was intended.

Comment: objdump's output is what I want to do, I'll fix my source adding that cmp. But this doesn't solve my problem

Comment: It looks like the problem is with gdb -- your instructions clearly should modify the registers contents, and if it's not showing that, it has a problem. At least from the looks of things, nasm is doing its job correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Flags are not modified by mov, so the jz at line 34 is not meaningful. If you follow the code from the initial `xor`, that is the only instruction that modifies the flags, so when the code reaches the jz at line 34 it just jumps (because the `xor` left it to zero). This does not explain the non-changing values of al or bl, but maybe some optimization took place that took into account the jz is always performed because of the xor.